# Devexpress grid details grid with a bar

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to figure out how to implement master-detail relationships between 2 tables in order to have a grid with grid details, just like this [example](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2163)

Now I got the same result as shown in the above link, but now I want to add a button 'Add' in order to add new records but it doesn't seem so easy.
I tried to create a control that contains a grid and a bar with buttons 'add' and 'edit' and create a relationship between it and the main grid but that didn't work either ..

Can anyone give me a hint how to do this ? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Data Navigator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument522)?

Comment: No, as I know its only for navigation and pagination, can I add/ edit rows using it ?

Comment: I've read about it, but it seems I cant add it to a gridview, but rather to a grid control and this is not what I want ..

Comment: Your are right. The data navigator is added to the Grid Control, but it offers functionality for both the main view or the nested ones. How the data navigator will interact with each level, i guess you can configure in the level itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you want to have a master detail grid, and above it, a bar that contain buttons to Add and Edit your items. If so, You can do the following :

- If you wish to put your bar in the top of the form, use a **bar Manager**.
- Otherwise : Try a Panel control, and in it, you put a **StandAloneBarDockControl** (enable you to put your bar in other places than the top of the form), and than, use the **bar manager** and the **xtragrid** controls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Embedded Navigator? Or is that no solution for you? Further you can build in a ContextMenuStrip. It is not exactly what you searching for but maybe it helps.